# What is the difference between Build and Build for Running in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build

Xcode has two options under the `Product` menu, one called `Build (Cmd+B)` and one called `Build for Running (Shift+Cmd+R)`.

What's the difference here? I can't find anything in the Xcode docs.

[image]